# Power BI Column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to write power bi function for new column, that checks 1 column finds rows in that column that have the same value, then for the rows that have the same value it checks another column, and if in at least 1 of the columns function finds value "Approved" it will return Approved for the columns with the same value in first column and if all of the rows have value "rejected" in the second column then function returns rejected for all of those rows.

I tried this

```
NewStatusColumn =
VAR SummaryTable =
SUMMARIZE(
'Agents Portal',
'Agents Portal'[proposalsid],
"GroupedData",
CALCULATE(
COUNTROWS('Agents Portal'),
FILTER('Agents Portal', 'Agents Portal'[proposalsid] = EARLIER(SummaryTable[proposalsid]) && 'Agents Portal'[uwprop_statusname] = "Approved")
)
)
RETURN
IF(
COUNTROWS(FILTER(SummaryTable, [GroupedData] > 0)) > 0,
"Approved",
IF(
COUNTROWS(FILTER(SummaryTable, [GroupedData] = 0)) = COUNTROWS(SummaryTable),
"Rejected",
BLANK()
)
)
```

but it only return approved, I can't make it work I tried different variations of this formula, but Didn't really try any other approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
NewStatusColumn =
  var sameIdFilter = FILTER('Agents Portal', 'Agents Portal'[proposalsid] = EARLIER('Agents Portal'[proposalsid]) )
  var cApproved = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Agents Portal'), sameIdFilter, 'Agents Portal'[uwprop_statusname] = "Approved") 
  var cNotRejected = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Agents Portal'), sameIdFilter, 'Agents Portal'[uwprop_statusname] <> "Rejected")

  RETURN SWITCH(TRUE(),
    cApproved > 0, "Approved",
    cNotRejected > 0, BLANK(),
    "Rejected"
  )
```

Example data result:

| proposalsid | uwprop_statusname | NewStatusColumn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Approved | Approved |
| A |  | Approved |
| A | Rejected | Approved |
| A | Approved | Approved |
| B |  |  |
| B | Rejected |  |
| C | Rejected | Rejected |
| C | Rejected | Rejected |
| C | Rejected | Rejected |